# Is there explicit formula for the smallest enclosing ball in $SO_3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

In Euclidean Space, given some points, we can find the smallest enclosing ball which contains all the points. And the center is known as the Chebyshev Center. But now I encounter a problem related to rotation and I would like to find the smallest enclosing ball on the manifold $SO_3$, using the metric of geodesic distance ([1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00332-021-09732-2)):$$
d(R, Q)=\operatorname{acos}\left(\frac{\operatorname{tr}\left(R^T Q\right)-1}{2}\right)
$$ To make this problem make sense, we may consider the points contained in a big ball with radius $\pi$.

I'm thinking about this question for quite a while, but I can't find much progress. Now I can solve this problem with some iterative algorithms, but due to this problem's simple form, I'm wondering if there is an explicit solution. I'm wondering if I can use something like stereographic projection to simply the problem.

Or, if I only consider the circumstances of 3 or 4 points on the $SO_3$, can I hope to get an explicit solution to this Chebyshev center problem?(To verify my iterative method). Any hints and help will be appreciated, thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit 2023/6/3:**

After some searchings, I find that the geodesic distance above is the bi-invariant metric defined on $SO_3$ and the angular distance in $S^3$ is also bi-invariant. The bi-invariant metric is unique up to scaling if the Lie group is compact and Lie algebra is simple. We can conclude that both these two bi-invariant metrics are unique up to scaling.

Now if I consider a diffeomorphism $F: SO_3 \to RP^3$ and locally the $RP^3$ looks the same as $S^3$, maybe we can consider the homomorphism: $\rho: SO_3 \to S^3$ and somehow prove that after the homomorphism, the new metric is still bi-invariant (I'm not sure if I'm right). If this holds, then maybe I can just study about the problem in $S^3$ ? But I'm still not sure if I'm right and how to interprete these in a precise way.

Also I think my previous thought of using the stereographic projection to simply the problem is not valid, for the smallest ball in $R^3$ after stereographic projection isn't the smallest on the $S^3$. So I'm still wondering how to tackle this.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit" in the case of the traditional Chebyshev center? I do not see the difference between the Euclidean case and the case of orthogonal group. AFAIAC, the issues are exactly the same.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean: if I can calculate the chebyshev center analytically considering the case of finite points (instead of a set). Sorry I am not familiar with manifolds and I don't have any intuitions about manifolds and $SO_3$ more precisely. Due to the different topology and distance definition, I don't know what I should learn about and apply to tackle the problem I encountered. So I can't really relate this problem with the one in the Euclidean Space. In a word, I want to know that if there is a way I can get the precise center given some points in $SO_3$. Can you give me some guidance?

Comment: $SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to the projective 3-space, imposing  $<\pi$ condition allows one to work with subsets of the round 3-sphere in $R^4$ where the metric is the angular metric.

Comment: So do you mean that the only thing I should do is to verify that the geodesic distance in $SO_3$ is corresponded to the angular metric in $S_3$? I'm wondering whether the "circle" in $SO_3$ is preserved by the diffeomorphism? Then in the  $S_3$ case I believe I can use the stereographic projection to pull the problem back to Euclidean space. Am I getting the things right?

Comment: I will add a more detailed answer later, when I have time.

Comment: @Moishekohan Thank you so much! That will be super helpful. I think I really need to understand the deeper relationship

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that there is a 2-to-1 mapping $S^3\to SO(3)$ where $S^3$ is viewed as the set of unit quaternions (see [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) for more on this map). This map preserves the standard geodesic distance (at least up to a constant scale factor depending on your convention). Using this covering map, we can associate each rotation $R\in SO(3)$ with a pair of antipodal points $\pm q\in S^3$. Given a set of rotations $R_1,\cdots,R_n$, there is a corresponding set of pairs $\pm q_1,\cdots,\pm q_n$, and the problem is equivalent to finding the smallest geodesic ball in $S^3$ which contains at least one member of each pair.

Since every geodesic ball in $S^3$ is the restriction of a geodesic ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$, you can find the minimal ball in $S^3$ by finding the minimal ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and computing its restriction to $S^3$

Comment: Hi! You said "finding the smallest geodesic ball in $S_3$ which contains at least one member of each pair." How can we carry out this procedure? By enumeration or there is some other more efficient ways to deal with that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm wondering whether "Since every geodesic ball in $S^3$ is the restriction of a geodesic ball in$ \mathbb{R}^4$, you can find the minimal ball in $S^3$ by finding the minimal ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and computing its restriction to $S^3$" is right. Intuitively this is right, but I don't know how to show that the restriction of minimal ball is necessarily the minimal ball in $S^3$. And are there any references for "This map preserves the standard geodesic distance"? I have a look at the wiki page and can't find about expression concerning that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nego Enumeration over all $2^{n-1}$ cases is indeed the most obvious way. There might be e.g. a convexity argument that scales better for large $n$, but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: @user1090529 To your first question, if you can show the $2$-dimensional case (i.e. that the intersection of a circle and a $2$-ball is a circular arc), the higher dimensional cases follow by a symmetry argument.

Comment: @user1090529 To your second, the answer depends on your familiarity with Lie groups (The homomorphism $S^3\to SO(3)$ induces an isomorphism of Lie algebras, and both groups admit exactly 1 bi-invariant metric up to scale). The most elementary way is probably to note that $d(R,Q)$ is exactly the minimal rotation angle of $R^{-1}Q$, and computing the same quantity for quaternions $\pm q_1,\pm q_2$ (using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Recovering_the_axis-angle_representation)) should give double the minimum spherical distance between members of each pair.

Comment: @Kajelad:I've been thinking about this problem. But now I think your approach may fail when the angles between rotations are larger than $\pi/2$. In quaternions, $d(q_A,q_B)=2arccos(|q_A \cdot q_B|)$. If the angle between rotations is larger than $\pi/2$, we should use $-q_A \cdot q_B$. There will be problem if we consider a group of points. Because for the Chebyshev center, its distance between some points can be calculated directly but others should be calculated using the antipodal point of the center. So this can't be solved using the enclosing ball in $\mathbb{R}^4$. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1090529 For a fixed set of quaternions $(q_1,\cdots,q_n)$ (with no sign ambiguity) the there's no issue finding the smallest enclosing ball in $S^3$ this way. For a set of pairs $(\pm q_1,\cdots,\pm q_n)$ you'll have to carry out the procedure for all $2^n$ possible choices of $+$ and $-$ and choose the ball with the smallest geodesic radius.

Comment: @Kajelad: Oh I get it! Thanks!